# Android: Record video using default app but simultaneously process GPS in background

Tags: android, android-intent, video, gps, android-service

**My problem**

I am building a test app and would like to test out the idea before implementing tons of features. Which is why I want to use as many default apps as possible.

1. I want to use the default camera app intent `MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE` to record a video.
2. I would then like to simultaneously start storing GPS and time stamp data to either a database or a file.
3. And then stop storing the GPS and time stamp data when the focus returns to my main activity.

**Things I've tried**

1. I thought it would be easy to use the **EXIF** data in the video file to store the data. But that seems to be harder than I thought. 
   I followed a few tutorials on the internet including this one http://www.androidcookbook.info/android-media/adding-video-metadata.html, BUT they seem a little hacky and don't really work with the newer API levels. I couldn't find any straight forward ways to manipulate EXIF data.
2. I thought of creating an **intent service** and starting my GPS service when I call the camera intent. But again seems hard because I'm not sure how to find out when the user actually starts recording the video.

I thought this was an interesting question and after looking around for some time I now turn to the SO community for advice.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks and Cheers